# Compare formatted dates to integers in Java

Tags: java

I would like to compare a Date I get from my local machine to an integer I get from a scanner. The date is formated as: `MMDDYYYY` such as `11232015` which is todays date. My integer is then `11192015`. I want to convert my date to an integer and then compare the true date vs. the one I got from my scanner:

```
Calendar c;
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
c.getInstance();
Date currentDate = c.getTime();
int dateFromScanner = 11192015;

Date formattedDate = df.format(currentDate);

if (dateFromScanner !> formattedDate {
// Do some stuff
} else {
System.out.println("This date has not yet passed.");
}
```

But I cannot compare dates to integers.

Comment: You naturally have a *date*... rather than converting the date to the integer, why not convert the integer to a date? Or better yet, read it as a string and then use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse it...

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formats it to a string, I cannot compare `if (dateFromScanner !> formattedDate {` two strings with a `!>`. However, how do I convert the integer to a date?

Comment: Well `!>` isn't going to work in Java anyway - it's simply not a valid operator. But `SimpleDateFormat` *parses* as well as formatting, which is what I was suggesting.

Comment: Btw, if you possibly can, you should use Joda Time or Java 8's java.time package instead of `Date`, `DateFormat` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    int dateFromScanner = 11192015;

    try {
        Date formattedDateFromScanner = df
                .parse(String.valueOf(dateFromScanner));

        if (formattedDateFromScanner.before(currentDate)) {
            // Do some stuff
        } else {
            System.out.println("This date has not yet passed.");
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a solution like this, it can give you some idea what do you do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar c = null;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter date value like yyyyMMdd.");
    int dat = sc.nextInt();

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    Date currentDate = c.getInstance().getTime();
    String formattedDate = df.format(currentDate);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);

    if (dat < Integer.parseInt(formattedDate)) {
        System.out.println("This date had being passed.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("This date has not yet passed.");
    }
}
```